# Confidence interval for population proportion estimate with replacement and known total population

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, proportion, population

So, I have an experiment that is equivalent to having a bag with $N$ balls of various colors in it, then drawing a ball, marking down its color and returning it to the bag. Repeat this process until I have $n$ samples. At the end, I count $x$ red balls.

So, I get an estimate that the proportion of the total population of balls that are red is $p=\frac{x}{n}$, and the total number of red balls is estimated to be $p\cdot N$.

From what I can find, the usual radius of the confidence interval around $p$ for an experiment where I pull $n$ balls out simultaneously is $z\cdot\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$, which is equivalent to a binomial proportion confidence interval (which I think is an appropriate way to treat my trials).

So I have two questions:

1. Shouldn't replacing the balls result in a wider confidence interval? In an extreme case of $n=N-1$, there will only be one ball not selected if sampled simultaneously, so one can guarantee a certain amount of accuracy, as the remaining ball is either red or not red. Whereas if the balls are replaced, there could only be one red ball that is sampled many times, which is not possible in the simultaneous sampling case. Hence my experiment would have a higher variance at large $n$.
2. Does knowing $N$ give me a better way to assess my estimate? It feels like knowing how many samples I took compared to the total value should be useful, but I can't seem to find any CI estimates which take this into account.

Comment: The formula $1.96\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ is useless as the margin of error for a 95% CI of $p$ because $p$ is unknown. The Wald CI substitutes $\hat p = x/n,$ where $x$ is the observed count of red balls in $n$ draws with replacement. This interval is useful only for large $n$ (say $n > 1000).$ Sampling with replacement is equivalent to sampling from an infinite pop, and the theory of the Wald interval is based on normal approx to binomial dist'n. // You are correct that sampling w/out repl gives smaller variance and shorter CIs. 'Capture-recapture' schemes can be used to est. pop size $N$.